# Remove a pointer to a parse user from an array

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a parseobject which consists of many objects, notably an array of consisting of ParseUser pointers.

When an individual clicks a button, the array should remove a certain User.
I don't get how to do this,

I have tried: 
mRideEdit.removeAll("Participant", (Collection) childuser);

Where mRideEdit is my ParseClass, Participant is the array consisting of ParseUsers, and childuser is the user I want to remove

Please help,

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced the same problem.

It originates from how the ParseObjects (including ParseUser) are saved on the server.
If you look at the console, you'll see it is actually an array of strings created from the JSONObject toString method.

The simple answer is - You're using it wrong.
There is no sense in saving objects in such a way (though it's very intuitive).
As you probably noticed - you don't receive them as objects with the getJSONArray method either and have to get them from their objectIds.

The best way to do this is using relations.

If you're set on avoiding relations, what I'd suggest is saving them as strings from the get go (objectId). That way add, addUnique and removeAll will work just fine.

Hope this helps.